# Sorting a multidimensional array in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to sort a multidimensional array in objective-c i know that i can sort a single dimensional array using the line of code below:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [someArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

I can't seem to figure out how to sort a 2D array like the one below:

```
 ( ("SOME_URL", "SOME_STORY_TITLE", "SOME_CATEGORY"),
    ("SOME_URL", "SOME_STORY_TITLE", "SOME_CATEGORY"),
    ("SOME_URL", "SOME_STORY_TITLE", "SOME_CATEGORY") );
```

If someone could provide me code that would sort the array by SOME_CATEGORY it would be of great help to me.

Thanks,

Zen_Silence

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `-sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:` or `sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:hint:`.

```
static NSInteger order (id a, id b, void* context) {
    NSString* catA = [a lastObject];
    NSString* catB = [b lastObject];
    return [catA caseInsensitiveCompare:catB];
}
...
NSArray* sortedArray = [someArray sortedArrayUsingFunction:order context:NULL];
```

Alternatively, create a custom class for your inner "array" (which is more like a record), and implement a `-compareByCategory:` method on it.

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks alot i was racking my brain about this for hours. Thanks for the help!